# Transgenic Plant-Gene source for introduction into host organism

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, biotechnology

Let's say the plant-gene itself is known, i.e. the exact neucleotide sequence is available in a gene bank (originally sequenced from a tree sample extracted RNA). Previous work has already successfuly inserted & expressed the gene in a host bacterium, say, E Coli.

My question is: Does subsequent work on inserting the gene into other host organisms also have to start from tree samples as source of the RNA & hence DNA?

Or is there a more direct route to convert a Neucleotide sequence from a gene database into actual DNA that can be inserted into hosts?

e.g. Are there machines that can take a sequence & synthesize the correct DNA molecules? Or not yet?

Comment: If you've access or someone else does and wants to answer, there's a good article through nature current to Dec. 2013 [here](http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v11/n5/full/nmeth.2918.html). 
The process is known as *de novo* synthesis.

Comment: @Kendall Thanks for the pointer. Googling up the term is getting me lots of info.

Comment: @Kendall Would it be fair to say that in cases like the one I described e.g. a tree gene as of today extracting the RNA & then purifying it & converting it into cDNA & cutting out the gene needed is a lot simpler / cheaper than de novo synthesis?

Comment: I guess what I am asking is when does one typically choose de novo synthesis over extraction from natural source material?